# Разделение строки на массив, где разделитель также является токеном

Tags: java

Как в `java` разделить строку таким образом, где разделитель также являлся токеном? Например, у меня есть строка `"var1 * var2 + var3"`, и я хочу, чтобы в результате разделения разделителями `"[\\+\\/\\+\\-]"` результирующий массив имел следующий вид:

```
{"var1 ", "*",  " var2 ", "+", " var3"}
```

Comment: я бы ручками писал. Что-то в духе `int prev = 0; for (int pos =0; pos<s.length();pos++) if (s.charAt(pos) in [ list ]) { res.add(s.substr(prev,pos-1)),  res.add(s.substr(pos-1,pos));  prev = pos;} res.add(s.substr(prev);`

Comment: делим по одному разделителю, а потом заносим в массив, разделяя их "разделителем". Потом, для каждого элемента массива повторяем ту же операцию для других разделителей.

Comment: а почему тут просто по пробелу не разделить?

Comment: @Grundy, потому что я хочу так же парсить выражения наподобие "var1+var2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать просмотр вперед и назад.

```
String s = "var1 * var2 + var3";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("((?<=[\\*\\+])|(?=[\\*\\+]))")));
```

> [var1 , *,  var2 , +,  var3]

**UPD**

Это [просмотр вперед и назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) (так же есть вариант с отрицанием) в регулярных выражениях.
Конструкции `?=` и  `?<=` являются просто условиями, а самим разделителем в данном выражении является пустая строка.

Comment: Отлично, кажется, это то, что мне нужно. А как это работает или где про это можно почитать подробнее?